# Does HTML5 offline webapp still work in Safari / iPad / iPhone?

Tags: ios, html, web-app

When I search Google about HTML5 offline features I can only find some answers dated 2010 / 2011. Nothing recent appears.

Besides the web app behaves erratic on iOS: sometimes it will work, even when navigating several times to cached pages, and then, all of a sudden, it "decides" it needs Internet connection and then, impossible to reload the home page from either the home screen icon, of from an URL in Safari. "Not connected!".

I'm using a manifest file called "example.appcache" and the related mime type is duly declared on my IIS 7 server.

Does someone have recent answers?

Answer (score -1):

It is still supported. You better check your code again

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions